# determinant of matrix $X$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Please hint me. ‎How ‎can I ‎calculate ‎determinant ‎of ‎matrix ‎‎$‎X‎$‎?‎
\begin{equation*}‎
‎\mathbf{X}=\left(‎
\begin{array}{ccc}‎
A&B&‎\cdots&B\\‎
B&A&‎\cdots& B\\‎
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\‎
B&B&‎\cdots&A‎
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}‎‎
‎where ‎‎$ B‎‎‎‎$‎denote ‎the ‎matrix ‎each ‎of ‎whose ‎entries ‎is ‎‎$‎+1$ and ‎$‎A$ is the diagonal matrix whose its entry is ‎$‎a$‎, ‎$ A ‎‎$ ‎and ‎$‎B‎$ ‎are squre matrices with the same order‎‎‎‎‎.‎

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices, and so let $X$ be a $kn\times kn$ matrix.

Let $X_0$ be the matrix obtained from $X$ by setting $A$ to be the zero matrix. The eigenvalues of $X_0$ are $kn-n$ (with multiplicity $1$), $-n$ (with multiplicity $k-1$), and $0$ (with multiplicity $kn-k$).

Now, $X=X_0+aI_{kn}$, where $I_{kn}$ is the $kn\times kn$ identity matrix. Hence $X$ has eigenvalues $kn-n+a$ (with multiplicity $1$), $a-n$ (with multiplicity $k-1$) and $a$ (with multiplicity $kn-k$). Since $\det(X)$ is the product of the eigenvalues of $X$, we get $$\det(X)=(kn-n+a)(a-n)^{k-1}a^{kn-k}.$$

Comment: thanks very very much. Do you allow me that I use your answer in my paper?

Comment: In a research paper?

Comment: yes, I want it for the proof of a part of theorem

Comment: Sure no problem.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know, I do it now.

Comment: @ Mohsen , the practice is to thank the people who helped you ; you can do that, or in the body of proof, either in the acknowledgments at the end of your paper. Moreover, it's good for you ; this shows that you have contacts with other researchers